# Hibernate setProjection - group by column should not come in the select list

Tags: sql, hibernate

Below is my table structure,

**Employee**

```
    id    Emp_id   value
_____________________________
    1      101      30
    2      101      40
    3      102      25
    4      103      28
```

I want to get max id record for same employee.

```
SQL: Select max(id) from Employee group by emp_id
```

My Hibernate Query:

```
DetachedCriteria detachedQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Employee.class);
                     ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
                     proj.add(Projections.max("id"));
                     proj.add(Projections.groupProperty("EmpId"));
                     detachedQuery.setProjection(proj);
```

**Hibernate generated Query:**

```
Select max(id), Emp_id from Employee group by Emp_id.
```

I want to select only max(id) not emp_id in the resultset.

Result should be

```
id
___
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

We can use eqProperty instead of groupProperty,

```
..........
detachedQuery .add(Expression.eqProperty("Emp.EmpId", "outerQuery.EmpId"));
.........
```